# MySQL Query to find delta of data modified after a specific date/time in DB and sync back from Azure to AWS DB in case of any issues

Tags: mysql, azure, amazon-rds, database-migration, rollback

I need your help on the below issue. We are migrating our Cloud infrastructure from AWS to Azure, and as a part of the rollback plan, we would like to know how the changes done across all the multiple schemas with multiple tables can be exported back to MySQL in AWS DB from Azure DB after any given time from the date of Migration. Simply saying, we want to sync back the Data from Azure DB back to AWS DB in case we have any issues after the migration as a part of the Rollback plan with minimal or no data loss. Currently, there is a sync from AWS to Azure but not vice-versa. We need a sync back from Azure DB to AWS DB in case of any issues in the Azure DB after the migration on any given date. Can I get the exact steps needed here? Also is it possible to get a SQL Query to find the delta of data added/modified after a specific date and time in the DB? Thanks, and regards.

We have synced AWS to Azure DB replication but have not done vice versa. We want the updated DB after the Migration if any issues to roll back to AWS DB with minimal or no data loss. We want the Data in the Azure to sync back to AWS DB if there are any issues.

Comment: is it possible to get a SQL Query to find the delta of data added/modified after a specific date and time in the DB? -- **Do you want query for Azure SQL database?**

Comment: Yes Aswin, as a part of the rollback plan we want to export all the updated data in Azure DB back to AWS DB in case we see any issues in the Azure DB like after a couple of days or a week later also. We need the Azure SQL DB queries for it so that we can export back the data after the migration to AWS DB with minimal or no data loss. We need the SQL query for it.

Answer (score 0):

You can enable CDC for tracking the changes happening in the table. Database will capture all changes that are made and store it in a table. I tried to repro this with sample data and below are the steps.

- Use below script to enable CDC to database and table which needs to be tracked for changes. Here I want to follow the table `SalesLT.Customer`.

```sql
/* Enable CDC on your DB*/
EXEC sys.sp_cdc_enable_db;

/* Enable CDC on your tables */
EXEC sys.sp_cdc_enable_table
@source_schema =N'SalesLT',
@source_name   =N'Customer', 
@role_name     =Null
```

- Once CDC is enabled for table, new table `cdc.SalesLT_Customer_CT` is created. This table logs the delta data information.
- Now data is inserted into this table.

[image]

- data in  `cdc.SalesLT_Customer_CT` :

[image]

Here _$operation=2 indicates data is inserted. Similarly, if data is updated, you will get data before and after modification in this log.

- You can disable CDC whenever required.

```sql
EXEC sys.sp_cdc_disable_table
@source_schema=N'SalesLT',
@source_name=N'Customer',
@capture_instance =  N'SalesLT_Customer'

EXEC sys.sp_cdc_disable_db
```

By this way, you can get the logs of data inserted, modified or deleted.

**Reference:** [Track, load, and replicate data changes on your Azure SQL Databases with change data capture (CDC)  | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/training/modules/azure-sql-replication/2-track-data-changes-with-cdc)